# Retain accented characters when importing an CSV file to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, csv, encoding, bulkinsert

The file I'm trying to import into SQL Server has foreign cities and states that are in Spanish.

ex: Seúl and Japón

I tried importing as nvarchar but the accents are replaced with �.

I tried also tried to collate the columns before bulk inserting data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.example', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.example;

CREATE TABLE example (
    transaction_id INT,
    country NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    state NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS,
    city NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    );

BULK INSERT example
FROM 'C:.csv'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FORMAT = 'CSV')
;
```

This resulted in the accents being replaced with different variations of ├. ( ├║, ├⌐, ├¡ )

I also tried messing around with the bulk insert like adding different CODEPAGEs and using 'widenative' or 'widechar' but with no progress.

Comment: CSV isn't an Excel file, it's just a text file. If you use the wrong encoding, you'll get garbled data. You need to specify the encoding in the `BULK INSERT` options with the `CODEPAGE` argument

Comment: What does the garbled text really look like? This can help determine what the actual codepage is. It's certainly not the server's collation. You can experiment with `CODEPAGE='ACP'` to use the Latin1 codepage, `CODEPAGE='65001'` to use UTF8 or a different codepage. If the file was UTF8 you'd see two characters for each accented character.

Comment: Can you change how the CSV files are generated? In this case the best option would be to both save them and import them as UTF8, removing any chance of garbled characters

Comment: It's a CSV file. I just mentioned its from excel in case that mattered at all. Using CODEPAGE='65001' seems to have fixed it, thank you.